# Section title exactly on the line above the following paragraph

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, memoir, line-spacing, baseline

I am trying to position section titles on the line above the following paragraph. By redefining the space above and below, I get two distinct undesirable outcomes:

### 1: The extra space pushes the bottom line to the next column

[image: empty line at bottom of column]

### 2: The title is joined with the paragraph

[image: title joined with paragraph]

```
\documentclass[landscape,a6paper,twocolumn,14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeforesecskip% only applies when section is not starting the page
    {-0.99999\baselineskip}% outcome 1
    %{-1.00000\baselineskip}% outcome 2
\setaftersecskip%
    {0.00001\baselineskip}% outcome 1
    %{0.00000\baselineskip}% outcome 2
\makeatletter
    \setsecheadstyle{%
        \fontsize{\f@size pt}%
        {0.99999\baselineskip}% outcome 1
        %{1.00000\baselineskip}% outcome 2
        \bfseries%
    }
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\setlength{\textheight}{10\baselineskip}
\setlength{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2\columnsep}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Setting `\aftersecskip` to `1\baselineskip` leaves an entire empty line between and setting `\secheadstyle` line height seems to have no effect. Increasing `\textheight` even by `0.99999\baselineskip` also seems to have no effect. Is there maybe a way to sneak in a `\par` / `\vspace` / `\skip` of some kind somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add some shrink factor:

```
\documentclass[landscape,a6paper,twocolumn,14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setbeforesecskip% only applies when section is not starting the page
    {-1.00000\baselineskip}% 
\setaftersecskip%
    {1sp minus 1sp}% 
\makeatletter
    \setsecheadstyle{%
        \normalsize
        \bfseries%
    }
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
\setlength{\textheight}{10\baselineskip} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-2\columnsep}
\setlrmargins{*}{*}{1}
\setulmargins{*}{*}{1}
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any scenario where this could misbehave? I'm wondering because I have had some issues with `plus` occasionally creating huge spaces between things, even for small values. Could this potentially create a negative space, making the title overlap the paragraph, or is the worst case scenario that it would join with it as in my second scenario? Could it ever *add* space? (In the non-MWE I'm also using the `grid` package if that's relevant.)

Comment: no it won't give negative space.